# No entry has been saved to database in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

I have created a table name `tenants` which have following column

```
class CreateTenants < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :tenants do |t|
      t.text :company_name
      t.text :work_area
      t.text :second_pref
      t.text :third_pref
      t.integer :who_are_you
      t.integer :number_of_bedroom
      t.text :other_specs
      t.string :budget
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :contact_number

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

And i am entering the data into in table by following form

```
        <%= form_for Tenant.new do |val| %>

                <%= val.label :company_name, "Company Name" %>
                <%= val.text_field :company_name, class: 'form-control' %>

                <%= val.label :work_area, "Work Area" %>
                <%= val.text_field :work_area, class: 'form-control' %>

                <%= val.label :second_pref, "Second Preference" %>
                <%= val.text_field :second_pref, class: 'form-control' %>

                <%= val.label :third_pref, "Third Preference" %>
                <%= val.text_field :third_pref, class: 'form-control' %>

                <%= val.label :who_are_you, "Are you Family/Bachelor?" %>
                <%= val.text_field :who_are_you, class: 'form-control' %>

                <%= val.label :number_of_bedroom, "Number of Bedroom" %>
                <%= val.text_field :number_of_bedroom, class: 'form-control' %>

                <%= val.label :other_specs, "Other Requirments" %>
                <%= val.text_field :other_specs, class: 'form-control' %>

                <%= val.label :budget, "Your Budget" %>
                <%= val.text_field :budget, class: 'form-control' %>

                <%= val.label :name, "Name" %>
                <%= val.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

                <%= val.label :email, "Email" %>
                <%= val.text_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

                <%= val.label :contact_number, "Contact Number" %>
                <%= val.text_field :contact_number, class: 'form-control' %>

                <%= val.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

    <% end %>
```

When i fill all the required filled and click submit, i see the following output in rails server log.

```
Started POST "/tenants" for ::1 at 2015-11-15 11:41:27 +0530
Processing by TenantsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {
"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"26KYMFmofF+A1UrF+eWu21nEGbVO3n2bUSPl8340k8hY1JQhYF2kfhOHLmlF+r1Tj5UB7h6H+IJ7MY+Rx+o4CA==",
"tenant"=>
  {
  "company_name"=>"Housing.com",
  "work_area"=>"Hiranandani Business Park",
  "second_pref"=>"Chandivali",
  "third_pref"=>"Vikhroli",
  "who_are_you"=>"Bachelor",
  "number_of_bedroom"=>"3",
  "other_specs"=>"Gym, Swimming Pool",
  "budget"=>"55000",
  "name"=>"Shravan Kumar Gond",
  "email"=>"shravan.ma.iitkgp@gmail.com",
  "contact_number"=>"9475593772"
  },
"commit"=>"Submit"
}
Unpermitted parameter: budget
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
```

Can anyone tell me, why this happening ?

Comment: Can you provide your controller code, specifically the strong parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are missing `:budget` in strong parameters of your `tenants_controller.rb` file. It should be something like this.

```
private

    def tenant_params
        params.require(:tenant).permit(:company_name, 
                                   :work_area, 
                                   :second_pref, 
                                   :third_pref, 
                                   :who_are_you, 
                                   :number_of_bedroom, 
                                   :other_specs,
                                   :budget,
                                   :name, 
                                   :email, 
                                   :contact_number)
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

> Unpermitted parameter: budget

This is your error - it means you're passing parameters to your `controller`, but it cannot save them in your `model`.

The fix is to set the strong params method (as `shravan40` suggested).

---

Since you're calling `Tenant.new` in your `#new` action, I would recommend using the following in your controller:

```
#app/controllers/tenants_controller.rb
class TenantsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @tenant = Tenant.new
   end 
   def create
      @tenant = Tenant.new tenant_params
      @tenant.save
   end

   private

   def tenant_params
      params.require(:tenant).permit(:company_name, :work_area, :second_pref, :third_pref, :who_are_you, :number_of_bedroom, :other_specs, :budget, :name, :email, :contact_number)
   end
end
```

There's also something you can do to polish up your form...

```
<%= form_for @tenant do |val| %>
   <% vals = [[:company_name],[:work_area],[:second_pref, "Second Preference"], [:third_pref, "Third Preference"],[:who_are_you, "Are you Family/Bachelor?"], [:number_of_bedroom], [:other_specs, "Other Requirements"],[:budget, "Your Budget"], [:name], [:email], [:contact_number]] %> 

   <% vals.each do |value| %>
       <% value[1] ||= value[0].to_s.gsub("_", " ") %>
       <%= val.label value[0], value[1] %>
       <%= val.text_field value[0], class: 'form-control' %>
   <% end %>

   <%= val.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Amazing last part of answer.

Comment: Thanks bud! If it works, otherwise it's just pretty fluff >.<